# how do I get my python package into conda-forge channel using anaconda upload?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda-forge

I am new to Anaconda.org
Uploaded a new python package using anaconda upload. As expected, it gets uploaded to a newly created channel specific to my account. But I would like my package to be available on conda-forge channel. anaconda upload does have a --channel option but its marked deprecated. found anaconda copy but not sure what should I specify for --to-owner when the channel to which I want to copy is conda-forge. Please help.

Comment: You should look at the documentation for conda-forge. This page seems relevant, for example: https://conda-forge.org/docs/maintainer/adding_pkgs.html